# react-testing-library - test component that uses useContext hook - context persists between tests

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a component that uses a custom hook. That hook uses context with the `useContext` hook. 
My problem is that the context persists between two consecutive tests. I've tried mocking the context, but that doesn't help.

You can see the code in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/l0192w68z though I couldn't get the tests to run there...

I also uploaded it to github where the tests actually run: https://github.com/uriklar/react-testing-library-with-use-context

I'd appreciate any pointers! How can I get a fresh context on every test run.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't mock the context, render the provider with your component: `render(<StoreContext.Provider value={}><MenuItem /></StoreContext.Provider>)`

Comment: Thanks @Gpx, but my MenuItem component uses a custom hook with useContext and imports the context via the provider. I tried doing as you said but I kept getting the same context, the one in Provider.js

Comment: I made a branch with your suggestion, test is still failing in the same manner: https://github.com/uriklar/react-testing-library-with-use-context/tree/wrap-with-context

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your `<MenuItem />` components are using the same (default) store between tests. There were a few issues actually and I talked about them all in [this livestream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yiialslPbc&list=PLV5CVI1eNcJgCrPH_e6d57KRUTiDZgs0u) and [here's a pull request](https://github.com/uriklar/react-testing-library-with-use-context/pull/1) showing what things you can do to improve things.

I hope that's helpful!

Comment: I'll write it here too for the public's sake. Passing a default store is mandatory if using typescript or else my context will not be typed correctly (plus, typescript forces you to pass a default o createContext)
You did show many options in the video that can help get around that. 
Thanks for your time